# AWK or SED to remove pattern from every line while using grep

Tags: unix, awk, sed

i have grep 2 columns , suppose col1 and col2. In col2 i want to remove a pattern which occurs in every line. how to use awk/sed for this purpose?

suppose `ps -eaf | grep b` would result into following output:

```
col1 col2       col3
1    a/b/rac     123
2    a/b/rac1    456
3    a/b/rac3    789
```

I want output to get stored in a file like this :

```
1 rac
2 rac1
3 rac3
```

Comment: `ps -eaf` will not lead to such output

Comment: Please post some sample data which resembles your real data. Vague questions will result in vague answers causing vague issues. Did I mention vague already?

Answer (score 3):

Vaguely speaking, this might do what you want:

```
$ awk 'sub(/.*b\//,"",$2){print $1, $2}' file 
1 rac
2 rac1
3 rac3
```

assuming file contains:

```
col1 col2       col3
1    a/b/rac     123
2    a/b/rac1    456
3    a/b/rac3    789
```

Comment: That did crack me up. This is a beauty though. Using `sub` like that removes the need for `/b/` pattern search. Brilliant!

Comment: You can add it under the "Vague" section of the upcoming awk book :-).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to pipe the output to

```
| awk '{sub(/^.*\//, "", $2); print $1, $2}'
```

The first command in the awk program changes the contents of the second field to only contain whatever was after the final `/` character, which appears to be what you want. The second command prints the first two fields.